# How to merge GitHub commits into VSTS repo

Tags: git, github, version-control, azure-devops

OK, we messed up.

The main developer sent an e-mail informing other developers to swith from GitHub to a new VSTS repo.

Some developers didn't read the e-mail and continued to work on GitHub.

Two weeks later we found out and now the developers that continued on Git need to merge their commits in VSTS.

But this is very difficult because there are hundreds of files changed.

How can we merge the two repos without losing anything?

If I clone the VSTS repo and simply copy the latest source files from GIT, will it undo everything that was added in VSTS in those 2 weeks?

Any thought appreciated.

Tks

Answer (score 4):

Nothing to worry too much.

1. Clone (or already have) VSTS repository
2. Add a remote of Github repository

`git remote add github https://github.com/account/repo`

3. `git fetch --all` (you now should have the 2 histories)
4. `git merge github/mybranch` (solve conflicts and history should be OK)
5. `git push`